# How to display the page title/content in the Posts page?

Tags: posts, pages

I made a home.php file and called it Blog.

It set it to be the Posts page, but I would like to add a title that will be displayed in that page (the title of page or content).

e.g:

```
Posts page:

    Page title
    (Maybe page content)

    == Posts ==

    Post Title
    Post Content

Post Title and so on
```

Comment: _home.php file and called it Blog_ not sure what you mean here. `home.php` is [template name reserved for home page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display), if you are trying to use it for named page template it will likely conflict.

Comment: Please clarify as Rarst said, are you using a native template file, ie. a file you just drop in a theme folder, or a named page template(ie. a file you attach to the page), note: it can't be both(that won't work correctly - as Rarst also pointed out).

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming the following:

1. You're using a Static Front Page
2. You have a separate static page assigned to display the blog posts index
3. You have created the `home.php` template file in your Theme
4. The static page assigned to display the blog posts index is titled **Blog**
5. You have added some post content to this static page

Because of the special, reserved nature of `home.php`, and also for `page_for_posts`, you cannot use the normal methods to access the `$post` object for the **Blog** static page. You *can*, however, retrieve the post title and post content for this page. **The key is to reference the post ID via `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )`.**

#### Page Title

Use [**`get_the_title()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title):

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) );
```

#### Page Content

Use [**`get_post_field()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field):

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) );
```

In both cases, wrap the output in an `apply_filters()` call, so that the post title and post content are rendered the same as they would be normally. Otherwise, the data returned via `get_the_title()` and `get_post_field()` would lack the usual formatting that WordPress applies via `the_title()` and `the_content()`, respectively.

Answer (score 9):

as what I understand, you need [`single_post_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title)

Comment: This is the correct answer.